# exterior algebra of representations of $S_n$

Tags: abstract-algebra, representation-theory, exterior-algebra

$$
\begin{aligned} \Lambda^{r} \mathbb{C}^{n} &=\bigoplus_{i=0}^{r}\left(\Lambda^{(r-i)} V \otimes \Lambda^{i} U\right) \\ &=\left(\Lambda^{r} V \otimes U\right) \oplus\left(\Lambda^{r-1} V \otimes U\right) \\ &=\Lambda^{r} V \oplus \Lambda^{r-1} V \end{aligned}
$$

Let $C^n=U\oplus V$ where $U$ is the trivial representation of $S_n$.
The second line is trivial as $Λ^r U = 0 , \forall r\ge 2$ as U is of dimension 1.

I have problem understanding the 3rd line.

$(Λ^r V ⊗ U) = Λ^rV $ seems dubious to me. Is it an isomorphism rather than an equality?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Yes, $\Lambda^r V\otimes U = \Lambda^r V$ is an isomorphism, as well as the first row (decomposition of $\Lambda^r \mathbb C^n$).

Comment: Thank you @lisyarus!

Comment: By the way, the isomorphism $W \rightarrow W \otimes U$ is given by $w \mapsto w \otimes u$ for any $0 \neq u \in U$, so it depends on the choice of $u$ and is not unique in general.